# jMeter login and activity test for 100 users

Tags: authentication, jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to create a test for login 100 users. However, the web application does not allow logging in with one login more than twice from one instance, nor does it allow multiple logging in. How would I create it? For 1 thread group user, I passed the test from login to activity and logout. If I give thread group 2 the test fails because of the token. Do you have any suggestions? well thank you

performance test JMeter

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what do you mean by "from one instance"

- If your application restricts concurrent logins using same credentials - you will need to have 100 credentials so each JMeter thread (virtual user) would represent a real user with its own username/password or whatever authentication information you supply. If you recorded a test with hard-coded username/password combination you need to parameterize it somehow, normally people go for [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) for this
- If the application restricts multiple logins from a single IP address be aware that it's possible to specify source IP address for the request. The setting lives under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

  [image]

  If you need each user to use an invididual IP address you will need 100 IP addresses (or aliases), they can again be parameterized using CSV Data Set Config. More information: [IP Spoofing With JMeter: How to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ip-spoofing-jmeter)